# Correct implementation of IShellFolder.EnumObjects vs IShellFolder.ParseDisplayName with large data?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, namespaces, shell-extensions

I was wondering in namespace extension development.

Whenever we browse to a specific virtual folder, `EnumObjects` is called, then I'm going to the server and getting all the items (thus, returning eventually `ppenumIDList`).

The question is, sometimes the explorer needs to retrieve a single item (using `ParseDisplayName`) from my `IShellFolder`.

I need to return a fully qualified PIDL with all the relevant serialized content. The thing is, it looks very inefficient to go to the server again, and search for this single item in the returned list.

The solution it seems is to cache  the list in memory. But I'm not sure where, I tried to cache the `EnumObjects` into a list, and clearing it every time `EnumObjects` is called.
But when the shell calls `ParseDisplayName` the list is empty. I'm guessing it's because it's deserializing my virtual folder again, and the list is of course empty there.

Is there a good approach to save the results somewhere so my `ParseDisplayName` would not have to go to the slow server every time?

Comment: Does it *"look very inefficient"*, or are you trying to solve a real performance issue?

Comment: @IInspectable real performance issue.
i'm getting a list of content from a server, and when ParseDisplayName comes, i have no idea how to fill in the PIDL (as i need to check if it really exists, and fill it up from data the server already returned to me - but those objects are already in front of me, why do i have to go to the server again?)